# .type() method in cypress when string is empty

Tags: javascript, cypress

Sometimes I want to pass empty string to .type() and I'm getting an error, for instance:

```js
data = {
  "test1": "test",
  "test2": "",
};
```

and when I assigned first case it's work:

```js
cy.get(...).type("test1")
```

The output:

```js
test1
```

But when I'm passing the next one, just empty string:

```js
cy.get(...).type("")
```

I've got an error that I can't provide empty string. How can I fix that?

This snippet of code is a part of a function so it must works for empty string as well as not empty string.

I tried something like this:

```js
cy.get(...).type('{backspace}', variable)
```

it's working when string is empty but also skipping variable if variable contain characters.

Comment: What exactly would it _mean_ to type no characters?!

Comment: {"string1": "characters", "string2": ""} - the second case dosn't contain characters

Comment: I can't disagree with that, but it doesn't really answer my question. Maybe just check if the string has any characters  first.

Comment: good point, do you know how to skip that in the simplest way like in one line of code? 'if variable is empty skip function' something like 'variable.isEmpty break'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on my own in other resources

```js
let array = ['test1', '', 'test2', 'test3']

for (let item in array) {
  cy.get(...).type(`{backspace}` + `${item}`)
}
```

and its work, even if string is empty.

Comment: Above you said you do not want to clear the field, but now you are using `{backspace}`.

Comment: Bro... the main purpose of that topic is to type out the value if string is not empty or how to handle empty string in the simplest way. How do you want to type something using .clear() method? You try to say that .clear('test@example.com') will works in my case? :D

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible for a user to type "", so neither can your test.

Use `cy.get(...).clear()` to make it empty.

Comment: I want to provide variable that contain characters or its empty, I do not want to clear the field.

Answer (score 2):

From the comments, looks like you have already come to the solution

For example,

```js
for (const key in data) {
  cy.get(key).type(data[key])     // fails when data[key] is empty
}
```

could be fixed with

```js
for (const key in data) {
  if (data[key]) {
    cy.get(key).type(data[key])   // only type non-empty data values
  }
}
```